# Firebase sort data by date

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort the data that i get by date, but it is not working.
This is the data that i want to sort:

```
{
"events": {
  "Saturday, May 6, 2016" : [ null, {
    "Id" : 3,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  }, {
    "Id" : 4,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  } ],
  "Saturday, April 8, 2016" : [ null, {
    "Id" : 1,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  }, {
    "Id" : 2,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  } ]
 }
}
```

I want them ordered by date, but the problem is that date is the key of a list of items.
How can i do that ?

I've tried this but it is not working:

```
ref.child("events").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let results = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        for (eventDate, arr) in results {
            let eventsDate = EventsDate()
            eventsDate.eventsDate = eventDate
            print(eventDate)
        }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: You should let Firebase create the id's for you. They are generated using the time when the data was created and it automatically sort the data for you

Comment: Don't you need to provide a key for `queryOrderedByKey()` ?

Comment: What do you do *inside* the callback? Most likely you're converting the snapshot to a dictionary, which indeed drops the order (since a dictionary is inherently unordered). To ensure you get the items in the correct/key order, loop over `snapshot.children`.

Comment: @Joakim This is the date of the event (when it takes place) so it is not when the event was added to the database.

Comment: @DanielLegler No because the key is the date .. and the function does not take any parameters.

Comment: `"Saturday, May 6, 2016"` is not a sortable date format. If you want to use the dates as key and order on those, store them in a format that allows that such as `20160506`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i don't want to get them in the correct order from firebase, i just want to sort the result by the date of the event.

Comment: and how would i sort them in this order ? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: And `queryOrderedByKey` will get them in the correct order. But you're not *doing* anything with the data in the code, so it's hard to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Look at the updated code. Thanks

Comment: Using dates as keys is generally not a good idea so you may want to re-think your structure (you're already experiencing an issue with sorting). Also, those nulls are going to cause a problem and the entire structure should probably be denormalized as well. Perhaps if you can describe how the data is being used and supply some code, we can suggest an alternative and a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data *is* being sorted by the key (date) but the problem is that your key is a string and strings are sorted *alphabetically*. So you're going to get all the **F**ridays first, then **M**ondays, and so on.

To sort *chronologically* you need to use a format that represents dates as ascending numbers, ie a timestamp. Firebase has a nifty shortcut to auto-populate [timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP) in a standard format when they're written to the database, but unfortunately that only applies when you need the time at which the data is *created*. However it's not difficult to produce a timestamp for any arbitrary date and time, and there are plenty of libraries that will convert that back and forth to any human-readable format you like in your UI. If you're *only* interested in the date you can probably get away with a simple sortable format like ISO-8601:

```
{
"events": {
  "2016-05-06" : [ null, {
    "Id" : 3,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  }, {
    "Id" : 4,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  } ],
  "2016-04-08" : [ null, {
    "Id" : 1,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  }, {
    "Id" : 2,
    "LogoImage" : "image_url",
    "MainImage" : "image_url",
    "Name" : "event_name"
  } ]
 }
}
```

It's also highly inadvisable what you're doing with [arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) in the data, but that's for another topic.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it and let you know about the result. Can you now please tell me what am i doing wrong with arrays in the data ? thank you

Comment: Arrays are generally a bad idea in Firebase except for very specific cases because they are converted to an integer-keyed map and it's hard to keep their indices consistent as the data is updated. It's better to use push ID's, priority, or sort by some other meaningful value as discussed in the article I linked. I can't give specific advice without knowing more about your app, but you may need to [denormalize your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) in a way that better supports the queries you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has its own keys (the UID it generates for you) and prioritizes those by default with the [orderedBy_](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#-queryorderedbychild) query. These default keys are prioritized by time/date added.

What you (likely) want is to order by "child", which are essentially your own keys.  Try the following:

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Id")
```

or whatever other child key you like.

Comment: this sorts them by id .. i want by date. This is the date of the event (when it takes place) so it is not when the event was added to the database.

Comment: Is "date" a "child" key in your database? If so, the same logic applies. Use date instead of ID. Find the child key in your db that corresponds to "date" (look at your db at firebase.com) and apply that key using the code above.